# Typescript does not recognize node_modules

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, node-modules

I have recently started a new project in Laravel and Vue 3, and decided to add typescript to play around with it. It was already painful to set it up to recognize vue SFCs, but now it just doesn't recognize any node_module that I import. E.G.:

```js
import Application from './Application'; // <- This is a custom class extending the Container
// @ts-ignore -> this is required since it will fail when compiling
import Container from 'random-node-library.js';
import ErrorHandler from './Exceptions/Handler';

const app: Application = new Application();
app.errorHandler(ErrorHandler); // this method exists in Container, but it's not recognized even though my class extends it
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,

        "baseUrl": ".",

        "removeComments": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        "strict": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": true,

        "importHelpers": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/*",
                "./resources/js/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "resources/js/**/*.ts",
        "resources/js/**/*.tsx",
        "resources/js/**/*.vue",
        "tests/**/*.ts",
        "tests/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.d.ts",
        "vendor",
        "public",
    ],
    "files": [
        "resources/js/shims-vue.d.ts",
    ],
    "types": [
        "node",
        "chrome",
    ]
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: why are you excluding `node_modules` in the `tsconfig` ???

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler otherwise it fails compiling because of all the packages not following the rules I set. That's the config I've seen everywhere

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no no, I'm using Vue 3, but this part is still before creating my app

Comment: Sorry mistook your question with another !

Comment: Ah, don't worry, it happens :)